# How to efficiently call a program with high frequency?

Tags: performance

I have a program (with source code) which is called by another programs with high frequency. And there are lots of computation cost to initiate the program. During each initiating, the same processing will be performed. Is there any way to improve the efficiency? For example, is it possible to keep the initiation status in the memory?

Comment: You can of course always redesign the software to stay resident between calls and accept multiple requests by various means. About the closest to a general mechanism for doing so without significant surgery is POSIX `fork`. It is difficult to give much useful advice without some knowledge of the particulars.

Comment: Caching of the execution result is one solution. However, only by looking at the actual source code can some worthy solution be suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Really calling the same executable and therefor starting a new process might be difficult to optimize, but since you have the source code, maybe recompiling as a library and calling it several times might be feasible?